# Django - Login page with Username, Company Code and Password

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

How to create a custom field in the User model where besides email and password it will also require Company Code in the Login page.

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2', 'company_code']
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    company_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.MyUser'
```

**ERRORS:**

```
    raise FieldError(message)
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for MyUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can it simple [customize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) `AbstractBaseUser` or `AbstractUser`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    company_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Don’t forget to point **AUTH_USER_MODEL** to it.

In your **settings.py**:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.MyUser'
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = [
            'username', 'email',
            'password1', 'password2',
            'company_code'
        ]
        ...
```

Comment: I am getting the following error with the code suggested : django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (username) specified for MyUser

Comment: @RoniX, I've updated my answer. Use `AbstractUser` instead `AbstractBaseUser`. Don't forget to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: ERRORS:
rec.Entity.users: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
        HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
rec.Gldetail.username: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the mode

Comment: @RoniX, use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your `Entity` model.

Comment: @RoniX, in all other models where you use the `User` model as a `ForeignKey` or `M2M` field, now you have to use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. See [Changing to a custom user model mid-project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227614/discussion-between-roni-x-and-nksm).

Comment: Happy to help ! 
Note: you don't need to change your question during/after answering. It confusing other users.